# What is the purpose of core.clj file?

Tags: clojure

I am just started on clojure and have a very basic question about *core.clj.*

What is a convention about it? What code should go there? Public API?

It is generated by *leiningen* when creating a project.
I have looked into source code of some libraries and this file is also present there (per package?).

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no defined meaning for it, but in an application it's often where you'll find the entry point, the `main-` function. For libraries, `foo.core` is often the namespace users will import to get your main functionality.

You don't *have* to do it that way, but it's a semi-predictable place to have the 'central bit' of whatever it is you're writing - even if your actual logic and algorithmic code is somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

Leiningen generates foo.core because it needs to pick a name and core is generic enough that it probably wont' be wrong. It's a style decision, but I typically opt to rename core.clj to a name that is actually meaningful for my project.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a template file emitted by Leiningen. If I run `lein new foo` there is no specific or standard meaning to the namespace `foo.core`. It is entirely legal for the namespace `foo` to be the main API container for a project. It's just a free file for you to start working in.

That said, if you have a project `foo`, it is expected although not enforced that all your code for that one project exist in the `foo.*` namespace. Leiningen will allow you to build a project with the files `src/foo.clj` and `src/bar.clj` and it is entirely reasonable for `foo` to require `bar`, however when packaging your code for distribution this is probably a bad idea.