# How best to set up core.clj

Tags: clojure

I saw the this question and its answers but they slightly miss the point of how best to author core.clj to make a library easily shared and understood.

[What is the purpose of core.clj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622208/what-is-the-purpose-of-core-clj-file)

One answer said we could do anything we want but probably shouldn't. :) I am looking for the path of least resistance, so core.clj it is.

But another answer said users would be using that path to get access to my library. That makes me think I have it backwards, with core being a few fundamentals. Instead it sounds like core.clj (its namespace) should pull in my other paths and effectively serve as its API.

Comment: It doesn't matter much. Here's an example of a library that does not use core (https://github.com/mishadoff/numberto/tree/master/src/numberto) and here is one that does (https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv/tree/master/src/clojure_csv). It all depends on how you decide to structure your library.

Answer (score 0):

Like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623507/3098550) to your linked question says, the `core` namespace typically holds the entry point(s) to an application or to your library. That being said, this is only a convention, not a necessity, you technically don't need to have a `core` module at all.

If your `core` modules holds only a few fundamentals that are used by other code fragments and you expect users of your library to call functions `foo` and `bar` from the namespace `yourlib.foobar` as entry points, you would probably be better of to rename your `core` module to something else to avoid confusing people checking out the code of your library. However, one notable pattern I've seen is that some people put the entry points / functions in a `yourlib.clj` module (`yourlib` namespace, not `yourlib.yourlib`), which serve as a thin facade to calls to functions in `yourlib.core`. So, in a sense, `yourlib.core` is really the "core" of your library, but doesn't provide the entry points itself.