# What is the difference between core.clj and inope.clj in a clojure project?

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between core & inope?

I have a very brief idea that core is like the main equivalent in Java. And inope is like an interface between java and clojure, although I dont understand the purpose of inope entirely.

I found this in a project and this is my understanding:
inope.clj is used for writing java clojure interoperable functions.

The namespace contents imply that it functions like core.clj here.

in this inope.clj file, they have imported dependencies and defined java-clojure interoperable functions in gen-class as such :

```
 (ns prject-avon.inope
  (:require [prject-avon.ioutil :as utl]
            [aero.core :as aero-core :refer (read-config)]
            [clojure.java.data :as clj-data]
            [malli.core :as m]
            [malli.util :as mu]
            [malli.instrument :as mi]
            [malli.error :as me]
            [malli.json-schema :as json-schema]
            
  (:gen-class
    :methods [ ^{:static true} [validateData [Object String] Boolean]
              ]))
   <Functions are defined here>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622208/what-is-the-purpose-of-core-clj-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just names, there's no significance to them. In particular, I've never heard of `inope` myself. The only way you can reliably judge is by the namespace's contents and their usage. It's also very possible that a single namespace contains all sorts of unrelated stuff.

Comment: I'd add: sometimes you'll see a namespace `foo.mylibrary.core` and `foo.mylibrary.impl` where `core` contains the "public interface" of the library and the `impl` namespace with the actual implementation containing functions that could be accessed but there's no guarantee that they will stay the same in later versions.